# Vat for specific countries

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, vat

I am courious if this can be done from backend.

European countries shipping: VAT code need to be added; 
Other countries: No VAT required.

I also need to hide VAT from invoice.

Magento: 1.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to System > tax > Manage Tax Zones & Rates.
2. Add your vat rule based on country & state.

[Europe countries list](https://www.countries-ofthe-world.com/countries-of-europe.html)